# suggestion how to train pre trained models by using Yolov4?

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I am looking the optimal way to train pre-trained models for YOLOv4
I have my local environment Debian 10 OS,

- GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER
- GeForce GTX 750 Ti

I planning to train the models based on different size of images, and the trained models I am going to use as part of microservices developed on java, or python.

Should I use any third party services like Google colab?
and the second question what the framework better to use ? (pytorch, tensorflow etc)

Thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this repo, https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet. It has all instructions for custom training, transfer learning and also colab training, inference script.

You can use the provided convolutional layer weights to improve results faster and on small dataset. Different dimension images can be used for training.

Custom training instructions,

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects

Training and inference in colab,

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_GdoqCJWXsChrOiY8sZMr_zbr_fH-0Fg